# Java - return vs void in simple example

Tags: java, return-type

What is the difference between the following two examples? Which one is the right one?
In first example I'm using return to print  some result and in the other one I'm modyfing variable `sum` and after that I'm trying to print it in the main method.

```
class A {
   double RR(double a, double b) {    
      double sum = 0;
      sum = (a + b) / 2.0;
      return sum;
   }
}
public static void main(String[] args) {   
    System.out.println(new A().RR(5.5, 6.5));
}
```

OR

```
class A {
   double sum = 0;

   void RR(double a, double b) {    
       sum = (a + b) / 2.0;
   }
}
public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.out.println(new A().RR(5.5, 6.5)); 
    //OR System.out.println(sum);

}
```

Comment: Have you tried compiling both?

Comment: You can't print `void` (i.e. *abscence* of result) in the second case. `A a = new A(); a.RR(5.5, 6.5); System.out.println(a.sum);`

Comment: you should at least test the code before asking about it. there is no right or wrong but if you are just making a calculation it is unnecessary to save the result as an instance field and then print it. the method can be static and return the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first example creates a variable (`sum`) inside the loop and returns it. (The `sum` variable wont exist outside of the method.) The second example has a `sum` variable in the `A` class and modifies it in the `void` method. (The `sum` variable will be modified in the specific `A` object) You could do something along the lines:

```
 double sum = 0;
 void RR(double a, double b) {

    sum = (a + b) / 2.0;
 }
 public static void main(String[] args) {

    A myObject = new A();
    myObject.RR(5.5, 6.5);
    System.out.println(myObject.sum);

 }
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no "right" or "wrong" here: you could use both approaches depending on the situation:

- The first approach is *stateless*, which is a huge plus, especially when concurrency is involved. You can call `RR` from multiple threads in different contexts, always getting the correct result. In fact, you can make `RR` method `static`.
- The second approach keeps a state - it's the `sum` variable. This means that if you call `RR` and then call it again before harvesting its result, you are risking to get wrong data. On the other hand, the result of last operation is stored for you in case you need it multiple times. This may or may not be required.

Note that the second approach requires a change:

```
A a = new A();
a.RR(5.5, 6.5);
System.out.println(a.sum);
```

Other things being equal, one should prefer stateless approaches (i.e. solution 1) because the API is simpler to use.